# Как передать данные через нажатие на кнопку в python Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Есть текстовое поле,

```
txt = Entry(window,width=15) 
txt.grid(column=1, row=0)  
txt.focus()
```

Причём не одно текстовое поле.
Есть кнопка,

```
btn = Button(window, text="Кнопка", command=clicked)  
btn.grid(column=0, row=8)
```

Так вот, как я могу получить данные через нажатие на кнопку и положить их в переменную.

Comment: В обработчике нажатия на кнопку получаете данные из текстовых полей и кладете в переменную (в список, например).

Comment: Это понятно, вот только как мне это сделать? Допустим у меня есть обработчик команды: def clicked():
... Что мне нужно написать в коде, чтобы осуществить вашу задумку?

Comment: Получить текст из поля ввода - `txt.get()`. Дальше уже все зависит от того что вам нужно с этим текстом делать. Можно записать в глобальную переменную, можно записать в поле объекта, можно сразу как-то использовать.

Comment: Вот несколько примеров( geeksforgeeks ) » https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-tkinter-entry-widget/

Answer (score 0):

Ссылки на поля положите в массив/словарь/объект. При нажатии кнопки обходите этот массив/словарь/объект и получайте значения.

Answer (score -2):

```
if btn == True:#типа если кнопка нажата,то ... 
    #делаешь что хочешь
```

Comment: Так работать не будет. Куда бы вы не вставили этот if, условие никогда не выполнится.